# Отключение основных клавиш в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как отключить все основные клавиши ?
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> и <kbd>Пуск</kbd>
Помогите, пожалуйста, если можно напишите весь скрипт на форму.

Comment: @LogDog, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу. Опять, рецидивист вы этакий! ;-)
А минус ставлю за "[скрипт](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_kiddie)", за это время уже можно было бы и просветиться.

Answer (score 1):

Выключение диспетчера задач:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  r: TRegistry;
begin
  r := TКegistry.Create;
  r.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  r.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System', True);
  r.WriteBool('disabletaskmgr', True);
  r.CloseKey;
  r.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно только в Windows 9x:
Отключение <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>:

```
var
 i:integer;
begin
 i:=0;
 SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SCREENSAVERRUNNING, 1, @i, 0);
end;
```

Отключение <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
var
 i:integer;
begin
 i:=0;
 SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFASTTASKSWITCH, 1, @i, 0);
end;
```

В Windows 2000/XP и более новых версиях подобного нет, но можно отключить через реестр, но это потребует перезагрузки системы!